# Image.FromStream(memoryStream) throws exception in palette

Tags: c#, .net, exception, gdi+, system.drawing

I am trying to convert a .wmf image of size < 1KB to jpg format. The conversion is successful, but the jpg image does not have the image and any colors, just shows black.

On investigation I found that `Image.FromStream(memoryStream)` throws exception in Palette.

> Exception details:
>
> Message: A generic error occurred in **GDI+.** Stack Trace:   at
>   System.Drawing.Image._GetColorPalette() at
>   System.Drawing.Image.get_Palette()

I have tested for other .wmf files with big size of 1 MB; the conversion goes fine. Can anyone please guide and help.

Comment: A WMF smaller than a kilobyte? What kind of data does it have? Does the file open in other editors? Are the WMFs that work vectors or bitmaps?

Comment: It is just a equation image extracted from Word document. It is opening in MS paint and Microsoft Picture manager 2010. I am able to convert it into differnt formats (jpeg,Tiff,BMP) using Microsoft Picture manager 2010.

Comment: I don't see how this could happen during the `Image.FromStream` call - the only call to `_GetColorPalette` I can see is from the `Palette` property, and as far as I can tell, that's not actually used anywhere in `Image`, `Metafile` nor `Bitmap` internally. Are you sure you're not the one trying to read the palette? IIRC only EMF+ files have a palette, so if your WMF is really a WMF and not an EMF or newer, it's quite reasonable the exception would occur when trying to read a palette that really isn't there.